# Capturing audio on a cloud VM (Debian)

Tags: debian, alsa, pulse-audio, icecast

I've followed a bunch of guides regarding ALSA, Pulseaudio, JACK, etc., but none have seemed to work. I'll be specific with what I'm trying to do. On a cloud-based Debian VM, I want to:

- Open a stream using `cvlc`
- Start an `icecast2` server on the same system
- Capture the audio stream from `cvlc` using `darkice` and send it to the local `icecast2` server

However, a cloud VM doesn't have an audio card. So I'm trying to set up a virtual device to make this work. So far, I've had no luck.

Why would I want to do this? Simple. There are several vloggers I follow who do live shows. They provide a podcast recording later on in the day, but they don't provide a live audio stream. I'd like to listen to them live when I'm out and about, but streaming YouTube is a great way to eat up your mobile data.

So, I want to:

1. Set up a small cloud server
2. Play their video stream with `cvlc`
3. Capture the `cvlc` audio with `darkice`
4. Re-broadcast the audio to a local `icecast2` server

I've gotten it to work in pieces. I'm able to:

- Get `icecast2` running on a cloud server
- Use my laptop to play the video stream with `cvlc`
- Capture the stream's audio with `darkice` (also on my laptop) and send it to the `icecast1` instance on the cloud server

However, I can't figure out how to get all the pieces working on the sound card-less cloud server. I know it can be done, and I know it requires setting up a virtual sound card. I've `modprobe`'d and `pactl`'d a lot of things, but I just can't get it to work.

Sorry to be long-winded, but I wanted to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out thanks to the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061291/linux-without-hardware-soundcard-capture-audio-playback-and-record-it-to-fil

First, install the required programs:

```
sudo apt-get install -y darkice icecast2 pulseaudio jackd2 alsa-utils dbus-x11

# If you want to use VLC, this will install the bare-minimum VLC without X:
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-video-output x11-utils- xdg-utils- vlc-plugin-samba- fonts-freefont-ttf- libnotify4-
```

I'm assuming you know how to set up `darkice` and `icecast` properly. The key is starting everything in the right order and with the right administrative rights (`jackd` needs to be run as `sudo`, it seems):

```
sudo service icecast2 start
sudo jackd -r -ddummy & sleep 0.25 ;
pulseaudio -D & sleep 0.25 ;
darkice -c darkice.cfg & sleep 0.25 ;

# If you are using VLC, play your audio, and it should work:
cvlc --network-caching 10000 --no-video [file-or-url]
```

That's it! I created a public Gist for my own sanity if you want a more detailed write-up:
https://gist.github.com/summersab/43d83fbfecaf9dffa665bacdc39cba10

I'd like to run this in Docker, but I can't get Icecast working - something to do with sockets, and I don't think I want to go down that path.